# Post form along with multiple files to Web API

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I'm still new to how Web API 2.0 works but I'm starting to get the hang of things. The one issue I've been having though is how to post a form along with multiple files that the user uploaded to my controller.

I guess I mainly need help with how to use `JavaScript` or `jquery` with `ajax` to post all of the correct values.

Here is a snippit of my HTML:

```
<form id="CreateAnnouncementForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="hidden" name="announcementTypeID"/>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Headline</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="headline" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">More Info</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="moreInfo"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Attachments</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="file" name="Attachments" multiple/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript/jQuery/Ajax that I normally use to post my form to the controller:

```
onAnnouncementCreate: function () {
    var form = $("#CreateAnnouncementForm");

    var validator = $(form).kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

    if (validator.validate()) {
        var options = {
            url: getApiUrl() + "/Announcement",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + getJwtToken(),
                "LocationId": getCurrentLocation()
            },
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            statusCode: {
                200: function () {
                    $("#AnnouncementCreateModal").modal("hide");
                    announcementViewModel.reloadGrids();
                },
                400: function (response) {
                    toastr.options = { "positionClass": "toast-bottom-full-width";
                    toastr.error(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        };

        $.ajax(options);
    }
}
```

Now I believe it would be best if I just created a `ViewModel` that contained both the `ViewModel` for all of the values in my form and have it contain an `IEnumerable` for the attachments that the users can upload within the form.

The trouble I'm having though is correctly adding the attachments to the form so that they map correctly.

My `ViewModel` will look like this:

```
public class AnnouncementCreateViewModel
{
    public AnnouncementViewModel Announcement { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

Of course I would then need to change the names in my form to reflect the new model.

If anyone can help me on how to post them to my controller that would be much appreciated as that's the only thing I'm still struggling with.

Comment: posting file attachments via AJAX is not as straight forward as you would hope for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously should give you some idea. there is an answer for asp.net mvc as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this turned out to be more difficult than I thought it would be. I decided to go an alternative route.

Since I'm already using the `Kendo UI` framework, I am now using the `Kendo Upload` widget to handle the uploading of my files. I have it asynchronously upload the files to my Web API controller and then I have a separate action to handle the form when it's submitted.

Of course I'm welcome to other answers as well that might be able to solve this issue by posting all of the data in one call but for now, this will do.